# Runtime error во время решения задачи яндекса

Tags: java

Тренируюсь решать задачи Яндекса.
Вот условие:
Дан упорядоченный по неубыванию массив целых 32-разрядных чисел. Требуется удалить из него все повторения.

Желательно получить решение, которое не считывает входной файл целиком в память, т.е., использует лишь константный объем памяти в процессе работы.

Первая строка входного файла содержит единственное число n, n ≤ 1000000.

На следующих n строк расположены числа — элементы массива, по одному на строку. Числа отсортированы по неубыванию.

У меня возникает Runtime error, а из-за чего - не могу понять. Не сказано же какая. В чём может быть проблема?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class WooHoo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n = Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());
        int prev = Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());
        System.out.println(prev);
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            int cur = Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());
            if (prev == cur) {
                continue;
            } else {
                prev = cur;
                System.out.println(cur);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Полный текст ошибки вместе со стеком в студию

Comment: Я бы отправила текст, если бы он у меня был) Код прогоняется по тестам на сервере и просто пишет RE

Comment: Может ознакомится с Yandex Contest Удаление дубликатов java https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1086727/yandex-contest-%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-java

Comment: Там же решение совсем другие. Мне кажется, моё тоже может работать. Если только понять, что может вызвать сбой.

Answer (score 1):

Я поняла в чём проблема. Размер входного массива может быть равен нулю, тогда код не будет работать.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class WooHoo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n = Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());
        if(n != 0){
            int prev = Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());
            System.out.println(prev);
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                int cur = Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());
                if (prev != cur) {
                    prev = cur;
                    System.out.println(cur);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Тогда уже пишите `if(n > 0) {`